# How to write these kind of functions in solr data config.xml

Tags: solr, solrj, solr4, solrcloud

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION page(IN i_app name character varying, IN i_photo_id  big int, IN i_page integer, IN i_member_id  big int, OUT o_similar_page_name character varying, OUT o_similar_page_id  big int, OUT o_similar_photo_id big int[])

DECLARE

v_limit    INTEGER := 4;

v_offset   INTEGER;

BEGIN

  SET SEARCH_PATH = '';

  v_start_time = DAYTIME();

  i_app name = UPPER(i_app name);

  IF i_app name <> 'DD' THEN

  RAISE EXCEPTION 'Enter Valid Application Name';

  END IF;

  IF i_page = 1 THEN

  v_offset := 0;

  ELSE  

  v_offset := i_page * v_limit - v_limit;

  END IF;
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

### Answer

No.

### Reason

Its not actually the purpose of SOLR. Functions has to be written in the DB level and the data that is retrieved out of query will be stored in SOLR for fast retrieval.

### ALTERNATIVE SOLUTION

You can create the function and call it in the select statement to index the data into SOLR.
Note : Final results fetched out of functions can be stored in the SOLR.

### Example:

```
CREATE FUNCTION CustomerLevel(p_creditLimit double) RETURNS VARCHAR(10)
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE lvl varchar(10);

    IF p_creditLimit > 50000 THEN
 SET lvl = 'PLATINUM';
    ELSEIF (p_creditLimit <= 50000 AND p_creditLimit >= 10000) THEN
        SET lvl = 'GOLD';
    ELSEIF p_creditLimit < 10000 THEN
        SET lvl = 'SILVER';
    END IF;

 RETURN (lvl);
END
```

### Query to used in SOLR  for Indexing

```
SELECT CustomerLevel(123123123) as CustomerLevel from CustomerRating;
```